# lowercase() function in python

Tags: python

I recently started learning python. Why can't the lowercase() function accept any input like the str() function?

I learned that str() takes an input and converts the input to a string and outputs the string. Why can't lowercase() take an input and convert the input in to lowercase letters and output the lower cased result?

Comment: .lower() is a method that converts the string object to lowercase. It doesn't accept any arguments

Comment: `str()` takes an argument because it can be used with values of almost any type. But `lower()` is a method of the `str` class, so it's called as a method: `string.lower()`.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense for `lowercase()` to be a regular function, since most types have no notion of uppercase and lowercase -- it's something specific to strings.

Comment: This is a similar question but I think its answer is not particularly satisfactory: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63531643/differentiating-between-built-in-functions-vs-built-in-methods-in-python

Comment: You can define your own lowercase function if you want `lowercase = lambda str_obj : str_obj.lower()` and then print it to see what happens
`print(lowercase("HELLO World"))`

Comment: @journpy: I shudder a bit when newbies are pointed to `lambda`s, let alone `lambda`s assigned to names (which have no advantage over `def` functions outside of code golf). The function the OP seems to want would also convert to `str` AFAICT, so using proper `def` functions, and performing the conversion, it would look like `def lowercase(obj): return str(obj).lower()`

Answer (score 0):

There *is* no `lowercase()` function, so your question is a little confusing from the get-go (`str` is not a function either, it's a class you construct, but it's very function-like, so I get the confusion there).

Python doesn't provide a top-level `lowercase` function because it's not a common interface many types need (`str`, `bytes` and `bytearray` are the only built-ins that support case changes to my knowledge), so rather than making it one of the special methods with built-in support, they leave it as a simple named method of the types that need it:

```
mystring = "mIxEdCaSe"
lowerstring = mystring.lower()  # Produces "mixedcase"
```

The ability to use `str` to perform the conversion, *then* use methods to manipulate the resulting string, avoids dumping hundreds of functions in the built-in namespace that just mean "call `str`, then this method on it" and makes the functionality more discoverable (once you have a `str` in the interactive interpreter, you can type `mystring.<TAB>` and see the available methods, rather than looking at hundreds of built-in functions, most of which would have nothing to do with strings).

---

As a side-note: There is *one* built-in that combines class construction and calling a simple named method on it: `sorted`, which is exactly equivalent to a function like:

```
def sorted(iterable, /, **kwargs):
    newlist = list(iterable)
    newlist.sort(**kwargs)
    return newlist
```

It exists mostly because that particular action (converting some other iterable to a `list` and sorting it) is performed so frequently (in my experience, I call `sorted` at least 10x as often as I `.sort()` a `list` in-place, because I'm usually using a "better" data structure for the task up until I need it sorted) that it was worth the built-in namespace pollution. But it's the exception, not the rule; for other cases, if you can do it with a class constructor followed by a method call, they expect you to do that.